# Can I put my own app on just my iphone?

Tags: iphone

I want to create an iphone app for personal use.

Can I just put it on my phone and use it or do I have to go through the iphone store process to get it on my phone?

Thanks.

Comment: Well you have to at least be able to *run* it - or else developers couldn't debug their own apps!

Answer (score 27, accepted):

As long as you have a valid developer certificate to sign the app and you have a development provisioning profile and your device is registered as a test device. For that you need to be registered as an iPhone Developer Program member.

In other words, you have to pay Apple $99 to be able to put your own app on your own phone.

Comment: Welcome to the world of scams. Please observe the master.

Comment: (little asterisk) per year

Comment: Good point samoz, this was all a master plan by Apple to earn $99 every time a developer wanted to write an iPhone app and install it on their own phone but not try and sell it in the app store. And this brilliant play has clearly worked as they now are the #2 USA company in market cap. Cause there are billions of developers doing this.

Comment: This is just sad. I wonder why Android allows it without any hassle or hindrance, while Apple just keeps on adding roadblocks to any use case. Any way it is for personal use.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can run your own apps on your phone. You need a paid iPhone developer account though.

Answer (score 1):

Purchase a developer account for $99 from Apple. Create a developer provisioning file and build to your device. The annoyance will be the provisioning file is good for a limited time, requiring you to update it periodically and rebuild.

Answer (score 1):

To run an app on an un-jailbroken iDevice, it needs to be signed. Registered developers get personal signing keys (and also have to register the device) which lets them test their apps. They also can do ad-hoc distribution, meaning compiling and signing an app so that other people can use it without being registered. This is limited in the number of users who can use it though.

Enterprise developers can sign apps for internal distribution, sorta like unlimited ad-hoc, but that program is expensive and unnecessary for what most people do.

Answer (score 0):

As pointed out by others here, you can sign up as a developer to temporarily install apps on your device for testing purposes, but you would constantly need to renew your phone's installed provisioning profile to keep using it over time.

The only way to permanently put your own application on an un-jailbroken phone is to publish it to the app-store and download it through iTunes. Of course, Apple would need to accept the app so you would need to face the same regulations as other apps sold via iTunes, and your app would be public to everyone.

Answer (score 0):

The main point here is that a **free** developer account on [developer/apple.com](https://developer/apple.com), provides developers a six-day window to download and test apps on the iPhone.  **For free**.